# Eliminate duplication from a SQL query to avoid returning NULLs from a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Have this MS SQL query

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS Total,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.AmountGB, 0)) END AS AmountGB,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.TaxAmountGB, 0)) END AS TaxAmountGB,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.AmountUS, 0)) END AS AmountUS,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.TaxAmountUS, 0)) END AS TaxAmountUS,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.AmountAU, 0)) END AS AmountAU,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ISNULL(p.TaxAmountAU, 0)) END AS TaxAmountAU,
...
...
...
FROM Page AS p
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT PageId,... FROM Campaign 
WHERE CampaignId = @Campaign AND...) AS c ON p.PageId = c.PageId
```

When there is no rows matching on the left side of the JOIN want to return 0s instead of NULLs that is why have

```
WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE...
```

Without having to define a scalar function, is there way to remove the repetitive

```
WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE...
```

or a more concise way to return 0's?

NOTE: Values in Page table (ex. AmountGB) can have nulls that is why the ISNULL(f.AmountGB, 0).

NOTE: Not allowed to change the table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much simpler as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       COALESCE(SUM(f.AmountGB), 0)) AS AmountGB,
       COALESCE(SUM(f.TaxAmountGB), 0)) AS TaxAmountGB,
       . . .
```

I also recommend `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       COALESCE(SUM(f.AmountGB), 0)) AS AmountGB,
       COALESCE(SUM(f.TaxAmountGB), 0)) AS TaxAmountGB,
       . . .
FROM Campaign c LEFT JOIN
     PageTotals f
     ON f.PageId = p.PageId
WHERE CampaignId = @Campaign AND ...
```

Comment: This helped! Btw, in your answer you left the END from my CASE at the end of the lines. Have the ISNULL() inside the SUM() as fields can have NULLs. Have RIGHT JOIN as right side of my JOIN because right side is joining many other tables (what wrote in my question is quite simplified version)